# Parsing website in Python

Tags: python, json, web

I wanted to parse elements from this website https://www.theice.com/coal.jhtml.
Specifically, values in the table:

`<table class="default condensed">` I want to extract each row and store it in my program. I know I can use `BeautifulSoup` to search for all `<tr class="(odd|even)">` tags and store that information. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this. For example, some websites have JSON load the data fields, but I couldn't find it in this case. Is there something alike that I can use for entries in this site?

Comment: Did you try `/search/Search.shtml?searchAsJSON=` ? Not sure if that's what you want, but it returns stuff as JSON.

Comment: So from `https://www.theice.com/coal.jhtml`, I tried something like this: `https://www.theice.com/coal/search/Search.shtml?searchAsJSON=`, I get a "page not found"

Comment: @Wes Your idea is right, I need to turn those elements in the page into JSON if possible

Comment: the URL I copied is from the root directory of the server

Comment: @Wes Could you please provide me with an example of this URL, I have tried it with `https://www.theice.com/coal.jhtml` and I can't get the stuff in JSON as wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good question for SO because the answer is specific to one website.  A quick glance at the website leads me to believe that the table is constructed server-side.

In general, here are some ways to figure out whether you can call the server directly rather than parsing HTML...

(1)  Is there easy to find/read JavaScript that makes an AJAX request?  If so, can you decipher what the arguments to the request mean?

(2) Use developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to see if the page is making requests for files that look like data (e.g. XML, CSV).  I'm not seeing that here (again, I looked quickly).

Lastly, respect the terms of use and robots.txt if applicable.  Creating valuable websites takes a lot of work and having people take stuff without permission is annoying, especially if they plan on profiting from the information they scrape.  A quick glance at your site suggests you are in the clear here.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is great.  I prefer [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and you might too.